# How to retrieve a particular cell value from a wpf datagrid without selecting the cell or the respective row?

Tags: wpf, datagrid

I m working with WPF `DataGrid` and I want to retrieve a `DataGridCell`'s value by using the `column` and the `row` indexes : all what I could do is this but it didn't work :

`myDatGrid.Columns[0].GetCellContent((DataGridRow)myDatGrid.Items[0]);`

Could you please show me the way to realize that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your cells value is going to be contingent on what the given column is bound to. The entire *row* will be the instance of your model.

Assume we have a collection of `Person` classes which we are binding to within our `DataGrid`.

```
Person p = ((ContentPresenter)myDatGrid.Columns[0].GetCellContent(myDatGrid.Items[0])).Content;
```

The `Content` property is going to return the underlying model for the *row*. If you wanted to obtain a given property you can do so by directly accessing the underyling object which should implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`, no need to fool with the `DataGrid` as you would in a WinForms application.

Comment: Thx Aaron for your help I really apreciate it , actually I guess I missed some casts which I should put , cuz the column I m using is a DataGridComboBoxColumn

I should actually ve done this :

        ((ComboBox)(myDatGrid.Columns[0].GetCellContent(
    (TestData)myDatGrid.Items[0]))).SelectedValue.ToString());

now it works

Answer (score 0):

OK I think I got it , I missed some casts that I should put , because the column I'm using is a DataGridComboBoxColumn

I should actually do this :

```
((ComboBox)(myDatGrid.Columns[0].GetCellContent(
(TestData)myDatGrid.Items[0]))).SelectedValue.ToString());
```

Now it works.

Answer (score 0):

I tried what has been proposed above and it did not work.

I struggled for a whole day trying to bind a ComboBox and select the correct value in a WPF Datagrid when it first loads, so I thought I would share my solution here in hopes that somebody else could benefit.  Sorry about the VB, but the concept should work in C# also.

First, if you are trying to get the values populated and selected when the grid first loads, you need to put your code in the correct event handler: LayoutUpdated. In other event handlers, the GetCellContent function returns Nothing (null).  You could also put this code in an event handler which handles an event occurring later, such as a Button.Click event, if that meets your requirements.

Second, the code:

```
        For i As Int32 = 0 To DataGrid1.Items.Count - 1
        Dim row As DataGridRow
        row = DataGrid1.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(DataGrid1.Items(i))
        If row IsNot Nothing AndAlso row.Item IsNot Nothing Then
            Dim cp As ContentPresenter = DataGrid1.Columns(3).GetCellContent(DataGrid1.Items(i))
            If cp IsNot Nothing AndAlso cp.ContentTemplate IsNot Nothing Then
                Dim dt As DataTemplate = cp.ContentTemplate
                If dt IsNot Nothing Then
                    Dim cb As ComboBox = dt.FindName("cbVendorNames", cp)
                    If cb IsNot Nothing Then
                        cb.ItemsSource = Vendors
                        cb.DisplayMemberPath = "VendorName"
                        cb.SelectedValuePath = "AS_ID"

                        cb.SelectedValue = "" ' set your selected value here


                    End If
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next
```

What this code does is (a) loop through all of the rows in the datagrid, (b) get the ContentPresenter for the cell selected (in this case, cell 3 in each row), (c) get the DataTemplate for the ContentPresenter, and (d) finally, get the reference to the ComboBox.  This allowed me to bind the ComboBox to an external datasource (a List(Of Vendor) and select its value.  This code worked for me.

I do not find this solution particularly elegant or efficient, but it does work.  If somebody has a better solution, please post it.